# Salesforce SOAP API using .NET - FieldSpecified = false, data not being entered into Salesforce

Tags: soap-api, .net

I'm using the Salesforce API via a web service in a .NET solution. I can successfully add an entity to Salesforce, and all of the cost related information is successfully added. When I try to do the same thing for a different entity, some of the data doesn't get added. The data is being correctly set on the .NET object that represents the entity, but the difference is that for the entity that's not fully updating, the corresponding property '...FieldSpecified' is 'false' for the fields that fail to update, so I'm sure this is the problem:

i.e. for *My_Entity__c*, the property

```
cost__cFieldSpecified = false
```

However the actual value of cost__c is correctly set, and is in the correct format (e.g it's correctly set for *My_Entity__c* as 90.5)

What is causing the FieldSpecified to be set to false, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the Enterprise API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you need to set the `x__cFieldSpecified` property to true if you want the current property value sent back to Salesforce.

It's related to elements like the following in the WSDL:

```
<complexType name="My_Entity__c">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ens:sObject">
            <sequence>
                <element name="cost__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
                <!-- ... -->
            </sequence>
        </extension>
   </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

So `cost__c` is nillable, but more importantly it has `minOccurs="0"`. How do you define something that could be both null and unspecified at the same time. The answer in this case is to have an additional `FieldSpecified` boolean property that indicates if the value should be passed back to Salesforce. That way you can still set the property for the field value to null and submit that to Salesforce.

See also:

- [Why fields with additional field “Specified” are always null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19519186/54026)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. There are 2 separate entities I'm updating. For the 1st one, when a valid value is supplied for the field, the corresponding '...FieldSpecified' value seems to automatically be set to 'true' - I don't need to explicitly specify it. For the entity that this isn't happening with, I can set those fields to true manually, but I don't understand why I need to do this with the 2nd entity and not the 1st. Also I'm concerned that this could risk errors if I'm always assuming that a value has been correctly specified. Is there a way to ensure that '..FieldSpecified' is automatically set?

Comment: For the entity that works, the wsdl entities for the properties where ...FieldSpecified gets automagically set to '"true" are - nillable="true" minOccurs="0"

Comment: What does the WSDL element look like for the entity that doesn't work? You might find the generated C# properties are automatically setting the corresponding `FieldSpecified` property in the `set` implementation.

Comment: The WSDL element is the same for the entity that doesn't work. For the entity that works and the one that doesn't, they both use the same generic 'upsert' method of the SforceService class, so I don't see how it could be a difference in the underlying implementation. Also that part of things is essentially black-boxed, so I'm unsure what I can do to ensure that the FieldSpecified gets set automatically. Maybe I just need to set the properties manually, although I'm keen to understand what's occurring and to be able to share that here

Comment: Doh! There's an intermediary 'set' routine that sets the values for the 1st entity when a unit test is run, which is the way I was testing that entity. It looks like setting those ...FieldSpecified properties manually is always required. Thanks Daniel, I'll award you the answer :)